# How can I use TypeScript to clone a node that contains an Angular selector?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, css-selectors

I have an Angular app, and in one component, the HTML contains a selector of another component, like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <selector>
        Text Content
    </selector>
</div>
```

In my Typescript, I'm trying to clone this div using the following:

```
var headerClone = document.getElementById('header').cloneNode(true);
```

I want the headerClone that gets created to look exactly like the div above, so the selector from the other component can work properly, but instead, here is what the clone looks like (from console.log):

```
<div _ngcontent-ikv-c2 class id="header">Text Content</div>
```

It isn't copying the `<selector>` tag, which causes the HTML/CSS of the selector component to not load. How can I get the clone to include the `<selector>` tag properly?

Comment: At first you need to delete this _ngcontent-ikv-c2 because this classes changes in every component try to use the `View.Encapsulation` in your ts file and that will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about getting the innerHtml and creating a new div?

```
var headerClone = document.createElement('div);
headerClone.setAttribute("id", "header");
headerClone.innerHtml = document.getElementById('header').innerHtml;
```